# Is it illegal to access a public file that contain private information?

Tags: web-application

There is a website that I was testing to see if they have any vulnerability.

To my surprise I found that one of the folders, like /docs with index of /, and they have a file that will contain all customer informations.

So basically I haven't done anything other than just opening a file.

Can this be consider as something illegal?

Comment: Did you have permission to test?

Comment: Are you asking if it's illegal as a vulnerability tester to access the file?  Or illegal that the website allows access to the file?  Either way I feel like we couldn't give you an answer as we're most likely not legal experts, and the answer then still depends on the country/state/province.

Comment: the website is a public website, and I just accessed a public folder on that website that contained a file with customers information.

Comment: @schroeder my first test was to open all folders looking for no index. :)

Comment: "I was testing to see if they have any vulnerability" - so you were poking around in areas where you knew you weren't supposed to be. ALWAYS get permission before testing.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because this is a question for a lawyer, not a security professional.

Comment: I hope you don't live in the US.

Comment: He who represents himself has a fool for a lawyer, but he's smarter than the man who accepts legal advice from the internet.

Comment: @peterpeterson how do you define a private website?

Comment: a website that can be only accessed with credentials/certificate/ip filtering... something that is not open to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is highly dependant on your jurisdiction and the jurisdiction of the server. But, in many jurisdictions, what you have described is "unauthorized access" and would be considered illegal/against terms of service/unethical.

As for your specific liability, you would need to ask a legal professional in your jurisdiction.

Comment: You and I aren't lawyers, and this is a legal question.  Personally I find it hard to believe that it's illegal to go into a directory and finding a file that's been indexed by a web server, and then download that file.  This question isn't a security question, and is very off topic.  It should be answered by a lawyer, not a security professional.

Comment: As I clearly mentioned in my answer. My answer isn't a legal answer, but includes potential legal implications. As the OP also mentioned that he was looking for unauthorized access, I felt that it was cogent to discuss that.

Comment: I also debate that the question is a "legal" one, regardless of the use of the word "illegal". One could say that the question is more general, in terms of "how much trouble am I in?", which could be on-topic. This is something that I brought up in the DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have explicitly expressed consent from the owner of the website, you should never test the website for its vulnerabilities. In the US, this falls into Computer Fraud and Abuse laws. When you are trained in ethical hacking, you get the opportunity to learn such laws, so you could do your work ethically and lawfully.

If you are new to security testing, use something like WebGoat or Metaexploitable to safely and ethically learn the subject.